# jquery change css from radio input

Tags: jquery

I have inputs working for a color selector but I'm missing something when it comes to radio inputs.
 I'd appreciate any help 
This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mpxgC/1/

-------HTML---------

```
<div>
<label>
    <input class=width name=group1 value=1px type=radio />1px
</label>
<label>
    <input class=width name=group1 value=2px type=radio />2px
</label>
</div>
<div class=number2></div>
```

-------CSS---------

```
.number2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    border-width:3px;
}
```

-------jQuery---------

```
$("input[name='group1']:radio").change(function (){
if(this.checked) {$("div.number2").css('border-width',$('.width').val());}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your jQuery to just:

```
$("input[name='group1']").change(function () {
        $("div.number2").css('border-width', $(this).val());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mpxgC/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Should be `$('.width').text().trim()` instead of `$('.width').val()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div>
<label>
    <input class=width name=group1 value=1px type=radio id="radio1" />1px
</label>
<label>
    <input class=width name=group1 value=2px type=radio id="radio2" />2px
</label>
</div>
```

```
$("#radio1,#radio2").change(function (){
if(this.checked)
{$(".number2").css('border-width',$(this).val());}
});
```